# Optimal GraphQL Server vs Web App deployment flow

Tags: deployment, graphql, continuous-integration, codegen

I have a graphql server and a web app deployed to 4 environments. When the web app builds, it codegens the required schema from the graphql server production environment.

[image]

This is problematic because a feature that requires a front and backend change requires a full 4 environment deploy for graphql followed by a full 4 environment deploy for the web app. Each deployment pipeline takes ~40 minutes.

Is there a common approach to solve this problem? I could build the web app schema from the first environment of the graphql server, but that risks promoting the web app to an environment where the graphql server change doesn't exist yet.